# Parsing big json data with php

Tags: php

I have a json like this:

```
[
    {
        "event": "hard_bounce",
        "_id": "323418ee24f744859ce7b7e01f28e0d1",
        "msg": {
            "ts": 1433426374,
            "_id": "323418ee24f744859ce7b7e01f28e0d1",
            "state": "bounced",
            "subject": "Subject",
            "email": "testMail@hotmail.com",
            "tags": [],
            "smtp_events": [],
            "resends": [],
            "_version": "HM-1sBYhpAPYoUvSCE2-Zw",
            "diag": "smtp;550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable",
            "bgtools_code": 10,
            "sender": "noreply@domain.net",
            "template": null,
            "bounce_description": "bad_mailbox"
        },
        "ts": 1433427203
    }
]
```

I have to get `email` value. How can I get it? I mean i have to get `testMail@hotmail.com`

How can I do it with php?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you even Googled this as it's pretty simple. You use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: PHP offers many convenient functions for such things. You should search for such thing. for example json offers a function to deserialize json encoded data.

Comment: By the way, it seems like you requesting mandrill or mailchimp api. They have libraries for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$decoded = json_decode($myJson);
echo $decoded[0]->msg->email;
```

Comment: This is returning null.

Comment: No it doesn't I've tested it with your JSON. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, that was my fault. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the variables that way.

From the manual:

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```